# java hibernate envers set other primary key for audit table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I want to map a Map in JPA Hibernate. The set up looks like

```
@Entity(name = "reservation")
@Table(name = "reservation")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Audited
public class ReservationEntity {

  // other fields

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "discountType")
  @Column(name = "discountAmount")
  @CollectionTable(
          name="discountTypeAndAmount",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="reservation_id")
  )
  private Map<DiscountType, BigDecimal> discountTypeAndAmount;

}
```

I can write the entity to the database the first time, but when I update the entity, I get the following error upon `entitymanager.getTransaction().commit()`:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with
the same identifier value was already associated with the session : 
[discountTypeAndAmount_AUD#{REV=DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 3, 
revisionDate = Dec 20, 2016 8:52:45 PM), element=10.00,  
ReservationEntity_reservation_id=1, mapkey=CASE_STUDY}]
```

In the exception, `CASE_STUDY` is one of the enums. `discountTypeAndAmount_AUD` is the audit log table auto generated.

It looks like the audit table `discountTypeAndAmount` was generated with a composite key made up of `REV` (revision id), `reservation_id`, `discountType`, and `discountAmount` and the error is thrown because envers doesn't know how to handle `BigDecimal` as part of a primary key.

Is there an annotation to set the primary key for the audit table to be a composite of just `REV` (revision id), `reservation_id`, and `discountType`? Since the field is a map anyway, there is really no need to have `discountAmount` as part of the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

@MapKeyColumn is used to specify mapping for the key column if key is a basic type, however I am not sure, but I guess that DiscountType is entity itself, so you need to map your key using @MapKeyJoinColumn.

Comment: His key is an enum (from a previous post), and XXXColumn annotations are for specifying a column name, not whether something is part of the PK of a table

Comment: If key is Enum, then he shall map it with @MapKeyEnumerated.

Comment: I tried adding the `@MapKeyEnumerated` as well and that didn't have any affect. `MapKeyColumn` actually works fine for the main join table. it's just when `@Audited` flag is applied envers has trouble with the audit table

Comment: If your map key is Enumerated, is it stored as Ordinal or as String in database?

Comment: It looks like it's stored as `int(11)`

Comment: So it is stored as Ordinal, you can change it to store as String (if required) by annotationg  Map `@MapKeyEnumerated(STRING)`